# Prove that $2^{n}≤n!,\forall n\in\mathbb N$ using mathematical induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction, factorial

I want to show that $2^{k-1}\leq k!\hspace{0.2cm} $  $\forall \hspace{0.2cm} k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried this:

For $n=1$, $2^{0}=1=1!$, the equality holds. Suppose that holds for n, then

$2^{k}\leq(k+1)!$
$2^k\cdot2=2^{k+1}\leq(k+1)!\cdot2\leq(k+2)!$

So, the inequality holds for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, your proof seems correct to me. You can change the problem statement as  $2^{n-1}≤n!$. Because, induction also uses variable $k$.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you!

Comment: to make it even more clear, i'd rearrange the equation as
$$2^{k+1} = 2\cdot 2^k \leq 2\cdot (k+1)!\leq  (k+2)\cdot (k+1)!=(k+2)!$$